# Number of trials required to get value in a certain range

Tags: probability

We do $M$ trials. In each trial the result is a uniform RV in $[0,1]$. What is the minimum no of tosses needed to be $90\%$ sure of getting a value in range $[0.8, 0.9]$.

I figure the answer is $9$ since each independent trial has probability of hitting this range as $0.1$. Can someone please confirm?

Thanks.

Comment: A single selection has a $\frac {9}{10}$ chance of missing the desired range.  Therefore n selections have a $ \left( \frac {9}{10} \right)^n$ chance of missing.    If you only try 9  you'll miss about 39% of the time...

Comment: Hmm... any reason why you approach this from the missing it direction. I assumed that each trial being independent and needing to hit 'at least once' means I can simply add the probabilities of hitting the interval.

Comment: It's easier to approach from the "missing it" direction because there is only way for them all to miss.  The other direction is messier because there are lots of ways to hit the interval (exactly 1 can hit, exactly 2 can hit, etc.).  You can't just add because of these overlaps.  Example:  if you toss a fair coin twice the probability that the first one is H is $\frac 12$ as is the probability that the second one is H, but the probability that at least one is H is not the sum!

Comment: Actually in your example as well, it is. The probability that first or the second is head and the other is tail is half. And both head is 1/4. So, at least once is 3/4 which is the same as 1 - both tail which is also 3/4. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes.  My point was that subtraction, approaching it from the "missing it" direction works, but adding (the method used in your original post) does not.  With the coin tosses, your addition method would say that you need 2 tosses to ensure an H.  Doing it by subtraction says that if you toss n times the probability of getting H is 1 - ($\frac 12)^n$ and if you want 90%, as in your post,  you'll need 4 tosses (which will give you a 93.75% chance).

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. Why don't you add that as an answer?

Comment: Ok; just posted it.

Answer (score 0):

As requested, here is my comment in answer form:

The problem with the method in the post is that you can't simply add the probabilities, there are overlaps.  Clearest example is coin tosses:  How many tosses do you need to have at least a 90% chance of getting at least one H?  If you simply added you'd think 2 tosses was enough to guarantee an H (as each slot has a probability of $\frac 12$).  But this is wrong, as the probability of TT is $\frac 14$.  Better to work from the other direction.  The only way NOT to get at least one H in n tosses is to throw n T in a row.  The probability of that is $(\frac 12)^n$, hence the probability that you get at least one H is 1 - $(\frac 12)^n$.  A little calculation shows that 3 tosses is insufficient, but 4 tosses gives you a 93.75% chance.

Approaching the original problem the same way, we ask for the probability that each of n trials misses the specified subinterval.  That probability is clearly $(\frac {9}{10})^n$.  Hence the probability that at least one of your trials lands in the right interval is 1 - $(\frac {9}{10})^n$.  We want the smallest n for which this is at least 90%.  The calculation takes a bit longer than it did for the coins; in the end we see that 22 trials just makes it, coming in at about 90.15%.